# Server.MapPath generating wrong URL

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Following code fetches image URL (`imgURL`) from sql database in a `View`:

```
<img src=@Server.MapPath(item.imageUrl); />
```

Following `Html` that it renders for the above line of code in the browser is wrong:

```
<img src="D:\Visual" studio="" projects\onlinestore\onlinestore\images\products\dry\baking="" goods\dalda.jpg;="">
```

Correct `Html` should be:

```
<img src="D:\Visual studio projects\onlinestore\onlinestore\images\products\dry\baking goods\dalda.jpg;="">
```

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: Just a note, but I would avoid having any logic in a razor view. That's what view-models are for. You may need to escape the rendered string?

Comment: You need to quote it - `<img src="@Server.MapPath(item.imageUrl)" />`

Comment: @Daniel Shillcock Code is passing a list of products from controller to view. Every product has a imageurl property and I need to show product list in a view.

Comment: And you know this still isn't going to work right? FIrst, this is a file path so this will be looking for it on the user's computer. If it works in testing it's because you are both the client and the server. So unless these images exist on the end users computer, this is not the way to go.

Comment: Instead of using `Server.MapPath()`, all you need is `src="@item.imageUrl"` assuming `imageUrl` is "/images/products/dry/baking goods/dalda.jpg" (which it should be)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - That was correct. Now there is correct path rendered in the browser as `<img src="D:\Visual Studio Projects\OnlineStore\OnlineStore\Images\Products\Paper Goods\margala.jpg">` but image link is still showing broken in the browser. I copied pasted this address from browser to file manage in windows and windows is displaying the correct image.

Comment: Check my previous comment

Comment: @StephenMuecke - `src="@item.imageUrl"` is rendering `<img src="~/Images/Products/Frozen Foods/22wheeler.jpg">` and image is broken in the browser. Do I need to save absolute path for the image in the database?

Comment: Then that suggests you do not have that file in that folder structure. And the easiest way to test that is just to drag one of your images into a view which will generate a `<img>` tag with the correct `src` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke - if `~` means root (`D:\Visual Studio Projects\OnlineStore\OnlineStore\`) then (`/Images/Products/Frozen Foods/22wheeler.jpg`) is the correct folder and path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179104/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues.

First the value of the attribute must be quoted (the html you are seeing is because the value contains spaces - at each space, the attribute ends and a new (invalid) attribute is created)

Second, you do not need `@Server.MapPath()` (and that should not be used in a view anyway). The values of `imageUrl` property should be in the format

```
"/images/products/dry/baking goods/dalda.jpg"
```

and then in the view its

```
<img src="@item.imageUrl" />
```

Comment: Salute. Gracious Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var pathOnDisk = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uri.AbsolutePath);
var decoded = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(pathOnDisk);
```

Comment: For every product i'm creating, its image path is saved as `~/Images/Products/Frozen Foods/22wheeler.jpg` i.e., relative path. Do I need to save `Absolute path` (`D:\Visual Studio Projects\OnlineStore\OnlineStore\Images\Products\Paper Goods\margala.jpg`) for each product in the database first?